# No color in CListCtrl report view

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I have done this before but to my surprise the CListCtrl will not show the text in color. I have the list view control on a dialog. I am using VS2010, is there something else needed that I am missing?

```
void CGameView::OnCustomdrawListBatsmen(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    //LPNMCUSTOMDRAW pNMCD = reinterpret_cast<LPNMCUSTOMDRAW>(pNMHDR);

    LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW pNMLVCD = reinterpret_cast<LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW>(pNMHDR);
    *pResult = CDRF_DODEFAULT;

    switch( pNMLVCD->nmcd.dwDrawStage )
    {
    case CDDS_PREPAINT:
        *pResult = CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
        break;

    case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
        pNMLVCD->clrTextBk = RGB(255,0,0);
        pNMLVCD->clrText = RGB(255, 0, 0 );
        *pResult = CDRF_NOTIFYSUBITEMDRAW;
        break;

    case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT | CDDS_SUBITEM:
    //  if( pNMLVCD->iSubItem == 1 )
            pNMLVCD->clrTextBk = RGB(0,255,0);
            pNMLVCD->clrText = RGB(255, 0, 0 );
        break;
    }
    *pResult = 0;
}
```

When I debug it, the control never even get passed the first case! I don't know is that? Do I need to set List control properties in resource view?

Comment: Add `CDRF_NEWFONT` to `pResult` after modifying colours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue, it was the last line:

```
 *pResult = 0;
```

This needed to be removed because it was resetting the whatever value was being set in the switch case.

Answer (score 0):

maybe, 
in CGameView, add:

1.

```
ON_NOTIFY(LVN_GETDISPINFO, IDC_LIST_Batsmen, GetDispInfo)
```

2.

```
void CGameView::GetDispInfo(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
```

in your CListCtrl class, add:

```
ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(NM_CUSTOMDRAW, OnCustomdrawListBatsmen)
```